# GWT TextBox, DateBox, and such doesn't share same base input-class

Tags: java, generics, gwt, input, parent-child

I'm currently working on an existing GWT project. In this project I've added a list on the view which looks something like this:

- Label1 : [TextBox]
- Label2 : [DateBox]
- Label3 : [TextBox]
- Label4 : [TextBox]
- Label5 : [DateBox]
- Label6 : [TextBox]

I've made a widget derived from a `FlowPanel` in which I create these Label-InputBox pairs:

```
import java.sql.Date;

import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Display;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox;

public class LabelInputWidget extends FlowPanel {

  private final Label      label;
  private final Widget     inputField;

  private static final int LABEL_AND_INPUTFIELD_WIDTH = 200;

  public LabelInputWidget(final String labelText, final Widget inputField) {
    super();

    this.label = new Label(labelText);
    this.label.getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.INLINE_BLOCK); // Used to put the inputfield next to the label, instead of below it
    this.label.setWidth(LABEL_AND_INPUTFIELD_WIDTH + "px");
    this.add(this.label);

    this.inputField = inputField;
    // The DateBox width looks smaller when the same width is set, so we'll add 4 pixels to line it up with the other Input-Widgets
    int inputWidth = LABEL_AND_INPUTFIELD_WIDTH;
    if (inputField instanceof DateBox) {
      inputWidth += 4;
    }
    this.inputField.setWidth(inputWidth + "px");
    this.add(this.inputField);
  }

  // TODO KC: Use a less ugly way of determine which InputField is used
  // POTENTIAL TODO KC: Use custom widgets for Numeric / Currency input fields
  public void setInputValue(final String value) {
    if (this.inputField instanceof TextBox) {
      ((TextBox) this.inputField).setValue(value);
    } else if (this.inputField instanceof DateBox) {
      ((DateBox) this.inputField).setValue(value != null && value.length() > 0 ? Date.valueOf(value) : null);
    }
  }
}
```

In the file where I create these fields I have the following:

```
private void fillEditedProperties(final List<Property> list) {
  for (final Property p : list) {
    if (!containsProperty(p)) {
      this.editedProperties.add(p);

      // The moment the property is loaded and known, we add it to the view
      Widget inputWidget = new TextBox();
      if (Type.DATUM.name().equals(p.getPdf().getType().name())) {
        final DateBox dateBox = new DateBox();
        dateBox.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
        inputWidget = new DateBox();
      }
      final LabelInputWidget labelInput = new LabelInputWidget(p.getPdf().getName(), inputWidget);
      labelInput.setInputValue(p.getValue());
      labelInput.getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.BLOCK); // Used to put the LabelInputWidgets below each other
      this.labelInputFieldsContainer.add(labelInput);
    }
  }
}
```

And I also want to validate the input when the user enters something (TODO / work in progress).

As you can see it's pretty ugly that a regular `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget` is used as shared Base class for the TextBox and DateBox. Because they don't share something like an InputBox-class I have to set their value after determining which (Input)Widget is used, and probably do the same for the ValueChangedHandlers to validate the user input, which I was just about to create.

Does anyone know a better solution to use both TextBoxes and DateBoxes in the same list of `LabelInputWidgets`, but instead of using ugly `instanceof` almost everywhere, just use one generic method?

If not I'll probably hide this behavior somewhere in order to make the code a bit more readable..

PS: I'm not 100% sure this is a suitable question for StackOverflow, so I made a cross-question on [CodeReview.StackExchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119770/gwt-textbox-datebox-and-such-doesnt-share-same-base-input-class) as well. I posted it here as well however for two reasons:

- Someone might have a suitable solution for this in a completely different way.
- The community here is bigger, so I will probably get an answer faster..

Comment: Well you can make LabelInputWidget abstract and have two implementations of it (Date-based one and Textbox-based one) with methods overloaded

Comment: @РоманГуйван I'm stupid, doh.. Luckily it's almost weekend.. Thanks for this obvious solution. You can make an answer if you want so I can accept it. (Can't believe I couldn't even think of something that simple..). Anyway, thanks, will start at it right away. The code certainly needs a lot of refactoring and reviewing from co-workers.

Comment: @Kevin - You can use InlineLabel instead of Label.

Comment: `labelInput.getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.BLOCK);` is unnecessary. FlowPanel renders as a `div`.

Comment: Ok, I've made it to a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can make LabelInputWidget abstract and have two implementations of it (Date-based one and Textbox-based one) with methods overloaded.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
public class LabelInputWidget<T> extends FlowPanel {

    private final Label         label;
    private final HasValue<T>   inputField;

...
```

where `<T>` can be a String or Date.

Comment: A `HasValue<T>` implementation seems indeed a good shared class between the two. I will use a combination of both your and Роман Гуйван's solution.